# error: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, json, aerospike

Hey there!

```
 # import the module
    from __future__ import print_function
    import aerospike
    import urllib2
    import json
    config = {
      'hosts': [ ('127.0.0.1', 3000) ]
    }

    try:
      client = aerospike.client(config).connect()
    except:
      import sys
      print("failed to connect to the cluster with", config['hosts'])
      sys.exit(1)

    key = ('ip', 'hit', 'trial')

    try:
      for i in range(0,255):
            for j in range(0,255):
                    for k in range(0,255):
                            for l in range(0,255):
                                    if not((i == 198 and j == 168) or (i == 172 and j > 15 and j < 32) or (i == 10)):
                                        response = urllib2.urlopen('http://ip-api.com/json/'+str(i)+'.'+str(j)+'.'+str(k)+'.'+str(l)).read()
                                        html = response.read()
                                        client.put(key, json.load(response))
     except Exception as e:
       import sys
        print("error: {0}".format(e), file=sys.stderr)


      client.close()
```

**Error**
error: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Can anyone please help in resolving this error? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You've already called `read()` here:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://ip-api.com/json/'+str(i)+'.'+str(j)+'.'+str(k)+'.'+str(l)).read()
```

And then you are trying to call `read()` again:

```
html = response.read()
```

---

Also, you are using `json.load()` afterwards which accepts a file-object, not a string. Either do:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://ip-api.com/json/'+str(i)+'.'+str(j)+'.'+str(k)+'.'+str(l)).read()
client.put(key, json.loads(response))
```

Or:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://ip-api.com/json/'+str(i)+'.'+str(j)+'.'+str(k)+'.'+str(l))
client.put(key, json.load(response))
```